# JS controls wont work on 2nd slider, not sure how to target

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm working on a website that has 2 sliders but the controls on the top slider do not seem to function

http://www.nathangriffithgc.com/gallery.html

How can I target the second slider? I've already changed the ID names but I'm not sure if that is affecting the slider.

Below is a snippet of both my galleries, you'll find that I renamed the top scripts the slides2, the bottom script is the original that works

```
<script>
                             var slideIndex = 1;
function showSlides() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}
    if (slideIndex < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-dot");
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" slide-dot-active", "");
    }
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " slide-dot-active";
 }
function plusSlides(n) {
    slideIndex += n;
    showSlides();
}
function currentSlide(n) {
    slideIndex = n;
    showSlides();
}
                                
var slide2Index = 1;
function showSlides2() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
    if (slide2Index > slides.length) {slide2Index = 1;}
    if (slide2Index < 1) {slide2Index = slides.length;}
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slide2Index-1].style.display = "block";
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slide2-dot");
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" slide2-dot-active", "");
    }
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " slide2-dot-active";
 }
function plusSlides(n) {
    slide2Index += n;
    showSlides2();
}
function currentSlide(n) {
    slide2Index = n;
    showSlides2();
}

                                
  window.addEventListener("load", showSlides); window.addEventListener("load", showSlides2);                              
                                
</script>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar i updated my post

Comment: You can't use the same `slideIndex` variable in both scripts, and you can only assign one function to `window.onload`.

Comment: In one of the scripts `var slideIndex` should be `var slide2Index`. You can use `window.addEventListener()` to add multiple listeners for the `load` event, instead of `window.onload`.

Comment: @Barmar how would i write this to use multiple?

Comment: Not sure how to write that out

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load", showSlides); window.addEventListener("load", showSlides2);`

Comment: Ok so all i have to do is add that to my script and change the slideIndex to slide2Index?

Comment: I haven't looked at your code thoroughly, but that's the general idea.

Comment: It would probably be better to write a function that implements all the similar code, and have it take arguments that specify each slider and the elements it controls.

Comment: im not sure how to write javascript that well... followed your advice.... no luck.... now the controls are swapped :/

Comment: There's way too much code here, can you simplify it to a *minimal* example?

Comment: no way to look in inspector? i added the scripts into one bracket

Comment: @Barmar updated the code

Comment: You have two `plusSlides` and `currentSlide` functions. They need to have different names for each slider.

Comment: @Barmar YOU ARE THE MAN!